# add custom H:i:s to Y-m-d in php

Tags: php, datetime

i have list of date with format 'Y-m-d'

```
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
2020-04-03
...
```

how do i add "00:00:00" for each list

```
2020-04-01 00:00:00
2020-04-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: For example `$myDate = '2020-04-01'`  Then your `$formatDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime($myDate));`

Comment: You can create instance of Datetime and manually set midnight time, then  format it as you want.

Comment: Why not just concatenate the strings? `$theDate .= ' 00:00:00';`

Comment: thank you @AlexKapustin. worked on my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert original date to timestamp first then again create a date with expected format.

Like this -

```
$date = "2020-04-02";
$required_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date." 00:00:00"));
echo $required_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime()` class converting a date string to a date-time object. And format it. You can try this.

```
$data = "2020-04-01";
$dateTime = new DateTime($data);
print_r($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add with foreach array if you list is array or object

```
foreach($dates as $key => $date)
{
$dates[$key] = $date.' 00:00:00' ; 
}
```

or you can use datetime

```
 foreach($dates as $key => $date)
    {
    $datetime = new DateTime($date);
    $dates[$key] = $datetime ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    }
```